# What algorithm does run through T type definition in static methods with only <? super T> <? extends T> args?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

`Collections` class has static method `copy`:

```
    public static <T> void ...copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
           //...
           ListIterator<? super T> di=dest.listIterator();
           ListIterator<? extends T> si=src.listIterator();
           //...
    }
```

Assumes I have hierarhy:

- Apple.class -> Fruit.class (Apple is subtype of Fruit class)
- Apple.class -> IMakeJuice.class (Apple is subtype of IMakeJuice interface)

and I execute:

```
List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Apple> appleList = new ArrayList<Apple>();
Collections.copy(objList, appleList);
```

Will T be cast to `Fruit`, `IMakeJuice`, `Object` or `Apple`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be the most specific type which satisfies the bounds, i.e. `T` will be `Apple`.

Quoting https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html:

> the inference algorithm tries to find the most specific type that works with all of the arguments.

Comment: @bayou.io I will gladly replace it with a better one if you'd care to provide it.

Comment: I mean it's a little too generalized. But it qualifies the sentence with "tries to", so I can't say it's wrong:)

Answer (score 1):

As Andy Turner already answered, `T` will be `Apple`.

For other similar questions, your IDE can tell you. I use Eclipse, but I assume the others will do this too.

If you add the following to any .java file:

```
class Test {
    void test() {
        List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        List<Apple> appleList = new ArrayList<Apple>();
        Collections.copy(objList, appleList);
    }
}
class Fruit {}
interface IMakeJuice {}
class Apple extends Fruit implements IMakeJuice {}
```

Then hover over `copy`, or click and press the F2 key, it will show the javadoc with `T` resolved, including the method definition:

```
<Apple> void java.util.Collections.copy(List<? super Apple> dest, List<? extends Apple> src)
```

This is also very useful for identifying which of many overloaded methods gets called, e.g. `String.valueOf(1)` and `String.valueOf((short)1)` both call the `int` version, while `String.valueOf(1.0)` call the `double` version.